# how to get image data of the pod's record

Tags: wordpress

normally I can access to the image field by

```
$pods->get_field('image');
```

But now I need to run my own query like

```
$pods = pods_query(MY QUERY HERE);
```

and I get result array but image field isn't included. So, how to get image value in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
`$picture = $pods->field('picture');`.
```

I can then pass `$picture` to `pods_image()` or use `$picture['ID']</code>` with a WordPress image attachment,

for example,

```
`echo wp_get_attachment_image( $picture['ID'] );`
```